# Dependent select elements generating different HTML data based on their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following select elements that are dependent on one another:

```
<select id="usercat">
    <option value="sold">Sold</option>
    <option value="bought">Bought</option>
</select>
<select id="catsold">
    <option value="cws">CW</option>
    <option value="ms">M</option>
    <option value="vas">VA</option>
</select>
<select id="catbought">
    <option value="cwb">CW</option>
    <option value="mb">M</option>
    <option value="vab">VA</option>
</select>
```

After that, I have some div elements:

```
<div id="cwcats">
<div id="mcats">
<div id="vacats">
<div id="cwcatb">
<div id="mcatb">
<div id="vacatb">
```

What I want to happen is the following. When the page is loaded the #usercat is assigned a value of "sold", and therefore, only two select elements are visible: #usercat and #catsold. The element #catbought is hidden.

If #catsold has a value of "cws" only the div with the id of "cwcats" should be visible (all other divs should be hidden).
If #catsold has a value of "ms" only the div with the id of "mcats" should be visible (all other divs should be hidden).
And the same goes for the value "vas".
The default value should be "cws" when the page is loaded.

Now, if the #usercat select element is changed to value "bought", the #catsold select element should be hidden and #catbought select element should appear with the corresponding div (#cwcatb or #mcatb or #vacatb) based on the previous value selected, or if there was none, with the default option which is the div #cwcatb.

As you can see, the #usercat select element is determining which "sub" select element will appear (the #catsold or #catbought) and the values inside those two "sub" select elements determine which divs will appear or disappear based on the selection, or more precisely, the combination.

I apologize for an extremely long and, I believe, quite confusing wall of text, but this is the only way I could describe what I am trying to accomplish.

Below I will post my extremely bad attempt at solving this issue which might help you understand the issue more clearly, but you should probably just disregard it altogether.

```js
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
$('#catsold').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'cws'){
        $("#cwarts").show();
        $("#marts").hide();
        $("#vaarts").hide();
    }
    if (this.value == 'ms'){
        $("#marts").show();
        $("#cwarts").hide();
        $("#vaarts").hide();
    }
    if (this.value == 'vas'){
        $("#vaarts").show();
        $("#marts").hide();
        $("#cwarts").hide();
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#usercat').on('change', function() {
      if (this.value == 'sold'){
        $("#sold").show();
        $("#bought").hide();
        $('#catsold').on('change', function() {
            if (this.value == 'cws'){
                $("#cwcats").show();
                $("#mcats").hide();
                $("#vacats").hide();
                $("#cwcatb").hide();
                $("#mcatb").hide();
                $("#vacatb").hide();
            }
            if (this.value == 'ms'){
                $("#mcats").show();
                $("#cwcats").hide();
                $("#vacats").hide();
                $("#cwcatb").hide();
                $("#mcatb").hide();
                $("#vacatb").hide();
            }
            if (this.value == 'vas'){
                $("#vacats").show();
                $("#mcats").hide();
                $("#cwcats").hide();
                $("#cwcatb").hide();
                $("#mcatb").hide();
                $("#vacatb").hide();
            }
        });
      } else if (this.value == 'bought'){
        $("#bought").show();
        $("#sold").hide();
        $('#catbought').on('change', function() {
            if (this.value == 'cwb'){
                $("#cwcatb").show();
                $("#mcatb").hide();
                $("#vacatb").hide();
                $("#cwcats").hide();
                $("#mcats").hide();
                $("#vacats").hide();
            }
            if (this.value == 'mb'){
                $("#mcatb").show();
                $("#cwcatb").hide();
                $("#vacatb").hide();
                $("#cwcats").hide();
                $("#mcats").hide();
                $("#vacats").hide();
            }
            if (this.value == 'vab'){
                $("#vacatb").show();
                $("#mctab").hide();
                $("#cwcatb").hide();
                $("#cwcats").hide();
                $("#mcats").hide();
                $("#vacats").hide();
            }
        });
      }
    });
});
$('#catbought').hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#usercat').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value == 'sold'){
            $("#catsold").show();
            $("#catbought").hide();
        } else if (this.value = 'bought'){
            $("#catsold").hide();
            $("#catbought").show();  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to worry about "bad attempts". That's how you learn. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic( more explicit naming conventions could do well here ) but if you could post your code in a working snippet I'm sure we can help you out. Also, what isn't working exactly?

Comment: When I change the "main" select element, the previous value it had is remembered but the divs that should be shown are not. I think the reason this happens is because I used the "on change" function in jQuery so it doesn't account for just switching the "main" select element without actually changing its "sub" select element's value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can leverage [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) combined with the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to show our target element.

We can also add a boolean overload to `toggle` to show and hide our drop downs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display.

Basically we've added a data attribute to the target `div` to indicate when to show them, using CSS to hide them an the surplus dropdown on page load. Comments have been added to the javascript to explain the process.

```js
/*FUnction to show the target*/
function showTarget() {  
  /*Hide all targets by default*/
  $(".targets div").hide();
  
  /*Generate an attribute selector*/
  var dataKey = $("#usercat").val();
  var dataVal = $("#cat" + dataKey).val();
  var selector = "div[data-" + dataKey + "=" + dataVal + "]"; 
  console.log(selector);
  //Show the element with the matching attribute
  $(selector).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Bought/Sold Change
  $('#usercat').on('change', function() {
    /*Use the boolean overload for toggle to hide and show*/
    $("#catsold").toggle($(this).val() == "sold");
    $("#catbought").toggle($(this).val() == "bought");
    
    /*Call our show target methof*/
    showTarget();
  });

  //Just call show target
  $("#catsold,#catbought").on('change', showTarget);

});
```

```css
#catbought {
  display: none;
}

.targets div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="usercat">
  <option value="sold" selected>Sold</option>
  <option value="bought">Bought</option>
</select>
<select id="catsold">
  <option value="cws">CW</option>
  <option value="ms">M</option>
  <option value="vas">VA</option>
</select>
<select id="catbought">
  <option value="cwb">CW</option>
  <option value="mb">M</option>
  <option value="vab">VA</option>
</select>

<div class="targets">
  <div id="cwcats" data-sold="cws">CWATS</div>
  <div id="mcats" data-sold="ms">MCATS</div>
  <div id="vacats" data-sold="vas">VCATS</div>
  <div id="cwcatb" data-bought="cwb">CWCATB</div>
  <div id="mcatb" data-bought="mb">MCATB</div>
  <div id="vacatb" data-bought="vab">VACTB</div>
</div>
```

You actually probably don't need the 3rd dropdown at all:

```js
/*FUnction to show the target*/
function showTarget() {  
  /*Hide all targets by default*/
  $(".targets div").hide();
  
  /*Generate an attribute selector*/
  var dataKey = $("#usercat").val();
  var dataVal = $("#cats").val();
  var selector = "div[data-" + dataKey + "=" + dataVal + "]"; 
  console.log(selector);
  //Show the element with the matching attribute
  $(selector).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
  //Just call show target
  $("#cats,#usercat").on('change', showTarget);
});
```

```css
.targets div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="usercat">
  <option value="sold" selected>Sold</option>
  <option value="bought">Bought</option>
</select>
<select id="cats">
  <option value="cw">CW</option>
  <option value="m">M</option>
  <option value="va">VA</option>
</select>

<div class="targets">
  <div id="cwcats" data-sold="cw">CWATS</div>
  <div id="mcats" data-sold="m">MCATS</div>
  <div id="vacats" data-sold="va">VCATS</div>
  <div id="cwcatb" data-bought="cw">CWCATB</div>
  <div id="mcatb" data-bought="m">MCATB</div>
  <div id="vacatb" data-bought="va">VACTB</div>
</div>
```